# how to get curl to download a json from web?

Tags: curl

i am trying to fetch data from a webserver via curl.
i can download the data directly with a browser like so:

https://fbinter.stadt-berlin.de/fb/wfs/data/senstadt/s_wfs_alkis?version=2.0.0&outputFormat=application%2Fgeo%2Bjson&typeNames=fis%3As_wfs_alkis&count=100000&service=WFS&request=GetFeature&bbox=392830.5359884375,5818765.207758436,393816.9642084504,5818080.847642038

but when i do

```
curl "fbinter.stadt-berlin.de/fb/wfs/data/senstadt/s_wfs_alkis?version=2.0.0&outputFormat=application%2Fgeo%2Bjson&typeNames=fis%3As_wfs_alkis&count=100000&service=WFS&request=GetFeature&bbox=392830.5359884375,5818765.207758436,393816.9642084504,5818080.847642038" -o test.txt
```

it just returns an empty file. what am i missing here?

Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: also tried to send the header like so ```curl -H "Accept: application/geo+json" "fbinter.stadt-berlin.de/fb/wfs/data/senstadt/s_wfs_alkis?version=2.0.0&outputFormat=application%2Fgeo%2Bjson&typeNames=fis%3As_wfs_alkis&count=100000&service=WFS&request=GetFeature&bbox=392830.5359884375,5818765.207758436,393816.9642084504,5818080.847642038" -o test.txt``` without success

Comment: I have try your curl and I got file with data successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change some HEADERS:

```
curl -A "Mozilla/5.0" -k -L -b cookies.txt -c cookies.txt -o file.json -s 'https://fbinter.stadt-berlin.de/fb/wfs/data/senstadt/s_wfs_alkis?version=2.0.0&outputFormat=application%2Fgeo%2Bjson&typeNames=fis%3As_wfs_alkis&count=100000&service=WFS&request=GetFeature&bbox=392830.5359884375,5818765.207758436,393816.9642084504,5818080.847642038'
```